# As of now did a radio telescope ever recorded something else than the silence of space?

Tags: radio-astronomy, extra-terrestrial, space-telescope

When a radio telescope listen to the Universe; a constant sound is recorded. Is it the noise "of the mic" : interferences? Scientists says that when they will notice variations on this basic constant same noise I call "the interference coming from the mic" they will conclude on an extra terrestrial source of sound; but in fact if is waves that are "listen" to. So, any news?

Comment: Vote to close because unclear what you are asking. This is probably not astronomy related, and not scientifically posed in any case. You can ask us and look at other questions and answers to understand how to improve the quality of your question and gets a good answer.

Comment: We don't just hear a 'constant sound'.  Just as a star is a point source of electromagnetic waves in the visible frequencies, it is also a point source of electromagnetic  waves of frequencies above and below that of light which a 'radio' telescope can detect.

When we turn those various EM waves into a light spectrum so we can see a picture they can be quite beautiful.  If we don't turn them into colors and simply plot them as we do on a frequency analyzer they look like any other point source of electromagnetic energy - a frequency with a bandwidth, much like a radio or TV station signal.

Comment: Continuing the comment above, the signal will appear as a higher 'noise floor' since the EM energy is not coherent.  Just as you point an antenna towards the TV station to receive a better signal so too do we turn our radio telescopes toward a star to receive a stronger signal from it.

Lastly, google the "Wow! signal" to see what the data looks  like in raw form - spoiler - it's just a bunch of alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 1):

Space is not quiet at all and is actually very noisy when listening via a radio telescope.  There are many sources of radio emissions in the universe, with pulsars being a very common one.  They can be quite interesting to listen when the signals are converted into sound frequencies we can hear. They range from slow clicks every few seconds to high pitched buzzing.

Here's a link with some examples:
http://www.parkes.atnf.csiro.au/people/sar049/eternal_life/supernova/pulsars.html

When using a wide angle antenna or one that uses a wide band of frequencies the mixture of all these emissions at once would just sound like background static.